# Tracing packets from source to destination for multi-hop communication using trace.nam in unetstack

Tags: unetstack

We implemented multi-hop routing protocol for underwater communication. Now we want to evaluate the performance of that routing protocol using parameters like- end to end delay, hop-count etc. We analyzed trace.nam to trace the packets from source to destination. Once a packet is originated from source, forwarded to next hop like that it will reach destination after multiple forwarding. But the problem is packet id at each forwarding node is changes. Due to this difficult to trace the packet and collect statistics (suppose 100 packet sent).

Not finding common parameter value in trace file to trace packets.

```
# BEGIN SIMULATION 1
n -t 1559191523.506000 -s 1 -x 0.000000 -y 0.000000 -Z 0.000000 -a 1
+ -t 1559191523.510000 -s 1 -d 0 -i 250111054 -p 0 -x {1.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
n -t 1559191523.511000 -s 2 -x 0.000000 -y 0.000000 -Z -35.000000 -a 2
n -t 1559191523.513000 -s 3 -x 0.000000 -y 0.000000 -Z -75.000000 -a 3
n -t 1559191523.514000 -s 5 -x 0.000000 -y 99.000000 -Z -118.000000 -a 5
n -t 1559191523.514000 -s 4 -x 0.000000 -y 0.000000 -Z -120.000000 -a 4
- -t 1559191523.564000 -s 1 -d 0 -i 250111054 -p 0 -x {1.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191523.958000 -s 1 -d 2 -i 250111054 -p 0 -x {1.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191523.969000 -s 1 -d 3 -i 250111054 -p 0 -x {1.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1559191524.005000 -s 1 -d 4 -i 250111054 -p 0 -x {1.0 0.4 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
d -t 1559191524.021000 -s 1 -d 5 -i 250111054 -p 0 -x {1.0 0.4 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
+ -t 1559191550.251000 -s 2 -d 0 -i 270543411 -p 0 -x {2.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1559191550.302000 -s 2 -d 0 -i 270543411 -p 0 -x {2.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191550.678000 -s 2 -d 1 -i 270543411 -p 0 -x {2.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191550.683000 -s 2 -d 3 -i 270543411 -p 0 -x {2.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191550.713000 -s 2 -d 4 -i 270543411 -p 0 -x {2.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1559191550.742000 -s 2 -d 5 -i 270543411 -p 0 -x {2.0 0.4 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
+ -t 1559191551.741000 -s 3 -d 0 -i 236268410 -p 0 -x {3.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1559191551.792000 -s 3 -d 0 -i 236268410 -p 0 -x {3.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191552.174000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 236268410 -p 0 -x {3.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191552.178000 -s 3 -d 4 -i 236268410 -p 0 -x {3.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191552.196000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 236268410 -p 0 -x {3.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1559191552.220000 -s 3 -d 5 -i 236268410 -p 0 -x {3.0 0.4 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
+ -t 1559191586.676000 -s 4 -d 0 -i -694431325 -p 0 -x {4.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1559191586.728000 -s 4 -d 0 -i -694431325 -p 0 -x {4.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191587.112000 -s 4 -d 3 -i -694431325 -p 0 -x {4.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191587.139000 -s 4 -d 2 -i -694431325 -p 0 -x {4.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191587.149000 -s 4 -d 5 -i -694431325 -p 0 -x {4.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1559191587.161000 -s 4 -d 1 -i -694431325 -p 0 -x {4.0 0.4 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
+ -t 1559191626.953000 -s 5 -d 0 -i -1642203870 -p 0 -x {5.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1559191627.005000 -s 5 -d 0 -i -1642203870 -p 0 -x {5.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191627.425000 -s 5 -d 4 -i -1642203870 -p 0 -x {5.0 0.4 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1559191627.430000 -s 5 -d 3 -i -1642203870 -p 0 -x {5.0 0.4 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
d -t 1559191627.446000 -s 5 -d 2 -i -1642203870 -p 0 -x {5.0 0.4 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
d -t 1559191627.462000 -s 5 -d 1 -i -1642203870 -p 0 -x {5.0 0.4 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME


+ -t 1559191741.605000 -s 5 -d 4 -i -1230929328 -p 1 -x {5.0 4.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1559191741.655000 -s 5 -d 4 -i -1230929328 -p 1 -x {5.0 4.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191742.268000 -s 5 -d 4 -i -1230929328 -p 1 -x {5.0 4.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1559191742.274000 -s 5 -d 3 -i -1230929328 -p 1 -x {5.0 4.2 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
d -t 1559191742.287000 -s 5 -d 2 -i -1230929328 -p 1 -x {5.0 4.2 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
+ -t 1559191742.300000 -s 4 -d 5 -i -2045618010 -p 0 -x {4.0 5.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1559191742.306000 -s 5 -d 1 -i -1230929328 -p 1 -x {5.0 4.2 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
+ -t 1559191742.316000 -s 4 -d 2 -i -1660400851 -p 1 -x {4.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1559191742.351000 -s 4 -d 5 -i -2045618010 -p 0 -x {4.0 5.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191742.736000 -s 4 -d 3 -i -2045618010 -p 0 -x {4.0 5.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1559191742.756000 -s 4 -d 2 -i -1660400851 -p 1 -x {4.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191742.762000 -s 4 -d 2 -i -2045618010 -p 0 -x {4.0 5.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191742.772000 -s 4 -d 5 -i -2045618010 -p 0 -x {4.0 5.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1559191742.786000 -s 4 -d 1 -i -2045618010 -p 0 -x {4.0 5.2 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
r -t 1559191743.330000 -s 4 -d 3 -i -1660400851 -p 1 -x {4.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191743.357000 -s 4 -d 2 -i -1660400851 -p 1 -x {4.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1559191743.358000 -s 2 -d 4 -i 1941993078 -p 0 -x {2.0 4.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1559191743.362000 -s 2 -d 1 -i 1563463759 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191743.365000 -s 4 -d 5 -i -1660400851 -p 1 -x {4.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1559191743.380000 -s 4 -d 1 -i -1660400851 -p 1 -x {4.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
- -t 1559191743.410000 -s 2 -d 4 -i 1941993078 -p 0 -x {2.0 4.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191743.787000 -s 2 -d 1 -i 1941993078 -p 0 -x {2.0 4.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191743.791000 -s 2 -d 3 -i 1941993078 -p 0 -x {2.0 4.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1559191743.813000 -s 2 -d 1 -i 1563463759 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191743.821000 -s 2 -d 4 -i 1941993078 -p 0 -x {2.0 4.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1559191743.849000 -s 2 -d 5 -i 1941993078 -p 0 -x {2.0 4.2 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
r -t 1559191744.383000 -s 2 -d 1 -i 1563463759 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191744.387000 -s 2 -d 3 -i 1563463759 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1559191744.388000 -s 1 -d 2 -i 1520738108 -p 0 -x {1.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191744.416000 -s 2 -d 4 -i 1563463759 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1559191744.440000 -s 1 -d 2 -i 1520738108 -p 0 -x {1.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1559191744.446000 -s 2 -d 5 -i 1563463759 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
r -t 1559191744.817000 -s 1 -d 2 -i 1520738108 -p 0 -x {1.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191744.843000 -s 1 -d 3 -i 1520738108 -p 0 -x {1.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1559191744.874000 -s 1 -d 4 -i 1520738108 -p 0 -x {1.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
d -t 1559191744.897000 -s 1 -d 5 -i 1520738108 -p 0 -x {1.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
+ -t 1559191798.872000 -s 4 -d 2 -i 706565595 -p 1 -x {4.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1559191798.925000 -s 4 -d 2 -i 706565595 -p 1 -x {4.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191799.500000 -s 4 -d 3 -i 706565595 -p 1 -x {4.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191799.527000 -s 4 -d 2 -i 706565595 -p 1 -x {4.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1559191799.530000 -s 2 -d 4 -i -476134347 -p 0 -x {2.0 4.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191799.535000 -s 4 -d 5 -i 706565595 -p 1 -x {4.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1559191799.536000 -s 2 -d 1 -i -70258 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1559191799.548000 -s 4 -d 1 -i 706565595 -p 1 -x {4.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
- -t 1559191799.582000 -s 2 -d 4 -i -476134347 -p 0 -x {2.0 4.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191799.958000 -s 2 -d 1 -i -476134347 -p 0 -x {2.0 4.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191799.961000 -s 2 -d 3 -i -476134347 -p 0 -x {2.0 4.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1559191799.985000 -s 2 -d 1 -i -70258 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191799.992000 -s 2 -d 4 -i -476134347 -p 0 -x {2.0 4.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1559191800.020000 -s 2 -d 5 -i -476134347 -p 0 -x {2.0 4.2 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
r -t 1559191800.552000 -s 2 -d 1 -i -70258 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1559191800.554000 -s 1 -d 2 -i -924478001 -p 0 -x {1.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191800.555000 -s 2 -d 3 -i -70258 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191800.588000 -s 2 -d 4 -i -70258 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1559191800.605000 -s 1 -d 2 -i -924478001 -p 0 -x {1.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1559191800.615000 -s 2 -d 5 -i -70258 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
r -t 1559191800.982000 -s 1 -d 2 -i -924478001 -p 0 -x {1.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1559191801.009000 -s 1 -d 3 -i -924478001 -p 0 -x {1.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1559191801.041000 -s 1 -d 4 -i -924478001 -p 0 -x {1.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
d -t 1559191801.063000 -s 1 -d 5 -i -924478001 -p 0 -x {1.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y BAD_FRAME
```

In the above trace.nam from line no. 1-36 beacons to set-up routing table.
Traces from line no. 39-98 indicating data packet forwarding originated at node 4 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

The `trace.nam` file in UnetSim currently only logs PHY frames. If you are analyzing higher layer protocols, this may not be the ideal log file to work from. It is perhaps better that you log your packets to `log-0.txt` in your agent using `log.info()` and use that for your analysis instead.

Comment: Sir, a intermediate node may be a forwarding node for many packets originated from different sources. a) How can i trace individual packet's if packet id is keep on changing when it passes through each forwarding node. b) How can i obtain packet id of packet

Comment: If you've implemented your own routing protocol, presumably you have the ID of the packet in the header, and the header is being decoded on the intermediate nodes by the routing agent. Why not log it at that point?

Comment: We designed routing protocol based on hop-count to reach single destination, which is on the surface of water and we are sending data using: router << new DatagramReq(to:1, protocol: Protocol.DATA, data: [1,2,3]); command. Kindly provide some code snippet to make a data packet (header + data) and send it to over network.